# Change path via script?

Tags: shell

Currently, after I shell into my devices I run this script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
export PATH=$PATH:/data/local/tmp
echo $PATH
/system/bin/sh
```

The sh at the end of the script inherits the new path from the export. Without it the change to path is lost when the script ends. How can I get around opening the extra sh? Is there a better way to temporarily change the path?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your final goal? `/system/bin/sh` wouldn't do anything useful to you in a script.

Comment: The goal is to temporarily change the path via script rather than having to enter an export PATH every time I log into a device. The call to sh is the only way I've found to make the path change persistent (for the session). Without it the change to path is lost when the script ends.